# Partial evaluation boolean formula in sage

Tags: boolean-logic, sage

Is there any way to evaluate a boolean formula in partial form. I make this question because when I run

```
import sage.logic.booleval as booleval    
t = ['&', 'a', 'b']
dd = {'b' : False}
print booleval.eval_formula(t, dd)
```

I get KeyError: 'a', when is obvius that **t** is False.

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't.
If you look up into the source file, which is `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/logic/booleval.py` on my computer, you can find that sage first transform `'a'` and `'b'` into `True/False`, for they need not to be. So they must **all** be defined.